# Magento 2 : VAT number validation by VIES

Tags: magento2, validation, vat

I want to implement VAT number implementation on my custom page by VIES. How to implement it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hello @Ankita Patel, Check this API Example https://www.phpclasses.org/package/10161-PHP-Validate-VAT-number-using-VIES-API.html#usage

Comment: Can you please give me example how to implement in Magento 2?

Comment: Not sure but I think this will help you, https://github.com/Dutchento/m2-vatfallback
or you can use this paid extension https://www.geissweb.de/magento-extensions/eu-vat-enhanced-for-magento-2.html

Comment: Yes. I saw this. But, I'm little bit weak to implement API in Magento so. It would be helpful for me if you give me example for that.